# symfony2 edit more entities in same page

Tags: php, symfony

How can edit more products entities in same page (no 1 to many).
In My editaction :

```
    $entities=$em->getRepository('MyBundle:Product')->findAll();
    $editForm=array(); 
    $deleteForm=array();
    foreach ($entities as $product )
    {
        $editForm [$port->getId()]= $this->createEditForm($product);
        $deleteForm[$port->getId()] = $this->createDeleteForm($product->getId());
    }

    return $this->render('MyBundle:Product:edit.html.twig', array(
        'entities'      => $entities,
        'edit_form'   => $editForm->createView(),
        'delete_form' => $deleteForm->createView(),
    ));
```

I have this error :

```
  Error: Call to a member function createView() on a non-object
```

And how update the edit.thml.twig to show all form update as table with only one submit ?

Comment: it does not make sense, you created arrays they don't have  `createView()` method. Read here how to use form collection: http://symfony.com/doc/current/cookbook/form/form_collections.html

Comment: How can do it without relation one to many ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I have fix this :
change the name of form:

```
public $name;
/**
 * @return string
 */

public function getName()
{
    return (string)'port_'.$this->name;
}
public function __construct($name=0) {
    $this->name=$name;
}
```

and in my controller
editAction :

```
        $entities = $em->getRepository('InfraProductBundle:InfraPortDdf')->findAll();

      foreach ($entities as $port )
    {
        $editForm [$port->getId()]= $this->createEditForm($port);


        $edit_view[$port->getId()]=$editForm[$port->getId()]->createView();
    }
 return $this->render('......:edit.html.twig', array(
        'entities'      => $entities,
        'edit_form'   => $edit_view,

    ));
```

in update action

```
 foreach  ($array_id as $key=>$id){
        if(!is_numeric(str_replace('port_','',$id)))
            continue;
    $entity = $em->getRepository('InfraProductBundle:InfraPortDdf')->find(str_replace('port_','',$id));

    if (!$entity) {
        throw $this->createNotFoundException('Unable to find InfraPortDdf entity.');
    }
    $editForm = $this->createEditForm($entity);
    if($editForm->submit($request->request->get($id)))
        $em->flush();


    }
```

in my edit.html.twig:

```
   {% for key, edit in edit_form %}
   ...
   {{form_widget(edit.description,{name:'['~key~'][description]',  'attr': { 'name' : '['~key~'][description]' } } ) }} 
   ....
   {%endfor%}
```

Answer (score 0):

This is not about Symfony2, but about PHP, you are calling a method onto an array...

Consider something like this :

```
$entities = $em->getRepository('MyBundle:Product')->findAll();
$editForms = array();
$deleteForms = array();
foreach ($entities as $product)
{
    $editForms[$port->getId()] = $this->createEditForm($product)
        ->createView();
    $deleteForms[$port->getId()] = $this->createDeleteForm($product->getId())
        ->createView();
}

return $this->render('MyBundle:Product:edit.html.twig', array(
    'entities'     => $entities,
    'edit_forms'   => $editForms,
    'delete_forms' => $deleteForms,
));
```

With a template like this one :

```
{% for form in edit_foms %}
    {{ form(form) }}
{% endfor %}

{% for form in delete_foms %}
    {{ form(form) }}
{% endfor %}
```

Comment: yes, more forms is showed and render the data , but in html there are the same code( foreach line)  where submit the dump of request  only the last data is submitted ...["pr_sfbundle_product"]=> array(4) { ["descSrc"]=> string(0) "" ["etatTx"]=> string(1) "2" ["etatRx"]=> string(1) "2" ["descDest"]=> string(3) "aaa" }  how fix that .

Comment: the solution is change the name of form. how do that? tks

Comment: It is not possible to submit more than one for at once (this is not about Symfony...). You will have to work "collection" form type instead of array of forms.